# Team Foundation Server 2015 query by feature

Tags: tfs

**How do I write a query in Team Foundation Server 2015 to show all work items of linked under a specific feature?**

I  want it like Feature = "Favourite" and all it's linked work items

Comment: Please be more precise where you have problems. In the meantime you can read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/track/using-queries)

Comment: The string "Favourite" is the title of the feature?

Comment: Yes  , 
   
 The string "Favourite" is the title of the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Select **Work Items and Direct Links** in the query, you'll see the linked work items under the Feature work item type:

[image]

Comment: I have done this but i want it like Feature = "Favourite" and all it's linked work items

Comment: No such query. You can combine more clauses to figure out the feature "Favourite", like Tags, etc. Or you can get the ID of "Favourite", then add a clause ID = XX. Or you need to use TFS API to get linked work items of "Favourite".